# Enable sub resource levels spring data rest?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, hateoas

I have an entity called `Document` and inside that I have a list of `dispatchDetails`. I have only created a repository for documents.When I make a **GET** request for a document by documentID, I get below result

```
{
    "docType": "SAP_ACCOUNTS_PAYABLE",
    "docStoreId": 456651,
    "qualityChecked": true,
    "format": "pdf",
    "bookingId": -1,
    "dispatchDetails": [
        {
            "dispatchQueId": 207443,
            "dispatchStatus": "S",
            "recipient": "fldcvisla12678.wdw.disney.com|#|/opt/apps/shared/shuttle/SAP/OUT/|#|f-tbxshuttlenp|#|D1$NeY984|#|SFTP|#|22|#|null",
            "description": "Upload :FileUploadDispatcher; FTP:null/null;\n2d89df3d-ca51-4d35-9528-439923fa48d4..",
            "dispatcher": "AD",
            "_links": {
                "generatedDocument": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571"
        },
        "generatedDocument": {
            "href": "http://localhost:7070/booking-documents-service/docs/5999571"
        }
    }
}
```

In `dispatchDetails`, I can't see a link for self. i.e. actions on sub resource level is not activated. Is there any way to generate that and enable sub resource level calls by adding anything to the existing repository without creating a separate repository for dispatchDetails? or with 2 repositories?

Simply what I want is to see both hateoas link and attributes loading inline.

Answer (score 0):

Set dispatchDetails fetch policy for LAZY.

Comment: I want both details and link